# How to tell git to ignore certain folders and files during a subtree merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-subtree

I have master branch with the following directory structure

```
templates/something.lib
templates/libs/1.lib
```

And I also have a templates_master branch with the following files (right in the root)

```
a.html
b.html
```

Then I go to master and load the templates into master templates folder

```
git read-tree --prefix=templates/ -u templates_master
```

which results into this master structure now

```
templates/something.lib
templates/libs/1.lib
templates/a.html
templates/b.html
```

Then I stay on master and introduce some changes into templates/a.html making several commits. Now I want this modified templates/a.html to go back into its original branch. I switch to templates_master branch and run this command

```
git merge -s subtree master
```

However this command not only copies the master:templates/a.html to templates_master:a.html but also copies those libs files so basically now my templates_master branch has everything that the original master templates/ had. Is it possible to tell git to keep certain files and folders in the master branch only or is this logic hardcoded on the git level, i.e. during subdirectory merge it uses treeish pointing to templates/ and everything inside templates/ is and can only be the child of templates/ ?

Comment: Yeah, cherry-pick is unfortunately not a solution here. I am trying to build an automated system that will be taking master template changes, moving those changes to a separate "master template" branch and then master template will get merged into theme branches: templates_theme1, templates_theme2, etc. The problem is the way product is structured - some stuff under templates/ folder is not related to templates and is not going to be needed into those final templates_theme1 branches.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I am pretty sure this is a requirement of the workflow of subtrees. They are after all called "sub trees". You cannot have super-project files in any of the paths of the sub-trees.

That said, this comes up a lot! I wonder if someone will ever think of a solution.

Imagine if you could merge 2 projects into the same folder? How would you handle common files like README? What would you expect if you add a new file; how could git know which project you're adding it to? There would need to almost be a new concept similar to that of clientspec mappings in perforce to accommodate such needs.

For now try to keep your sub-projects in ***sub folders***.